# Decide when to refresh OAUTH2 token with Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

I believe this is mostly a question about best practices.

I have an OAUTH2 provider that issues access tokens (valid for 10 hours) as long as refresh tokens.

I found [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/52) that it is pretty easy to refresh the access token but I cannot understand how to decide when it is time to refresh.

The easy answer is probably "when it does not work any more", meaning when I get a  HTTP 401 from the backend.
The problem with this solution is that it is not that efficient, plus I can only assume I got a 401 because the token has expired.

I my django app I found that the `user social auth` has an `Extra data` field containing something like this:

`{
  "scope": "read write", 
  "expires": 36000, 
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}`

but I am not sure how to use the `expires` field.

So my question is: how do I know if an access token has expired and I need to refresh it?

**EDIT**:
I just found [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-social-auth/9Frw6B1PTKY/bjbmxZb_OyMJ) that seems relevant, but I cannot understand how to plug this new function in the pipeline in order to work during the token refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. 
The reason I was initially confused was because there are actually two cases:

1. When the user comes from a login, so when basically the pipeline get executed.
2. When the token is refreshed calling the user social auth method `refresh_token`

**To solve the first case**

I created a new function for the pipeline:

```
def set_last_update(details, *args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    """
    Pipeline function to add extra information about when the social auth
    profile has been updated.
    Args:
        details (dict): dictionary of informations about the user
    Returns:
        dict: updated details dictionary
    """
    details['updated_at'] = datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
    return details
```

in the settings I added it in the pipeline right before the `load_extra_data`

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    # the following custom pipeline func goes before load_extra_data
    'backends.pipeline_api.set_last_update',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'backends.pipeline_api.update_profile_from_edx',
    'backends.pipeline_api.update_from_linkedin',
)
```

and, still in the settings I added the new field in the extra data.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_EDXORG_EXTRA_DATA = ['updated_at']
```

**For the second case:**

I overwrote the `refresh_token` method of my backend to add the extra field.

```
def refresh_token(self, token, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Overridden method to add extra info during refresh token.
    Args:
        token (str): valid refresh token
    Returns:
        dict of information about the user
    """
    response = super(EdxOrgOAuth2, self).refresh_token(token, *args, **kwargs)
    response['updated_at'] = datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
    return response
```

Still in the backend class, I added an extra field to extract the `expires_in` field coming from the server.

```
EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('refresh_token', 'refresh_token', True),
    ('expires_in', 'expires_in'),
    ('token_type', 'token_type', True),
    ('scope', 'scope'),
]
```

At this point I have the timestamp when the access token has been created (`updated_at`) and the amount of seconds it will be valid (`expires_in`).

NOTE: the `updated_at` is an approximation, because it is created on the client and not on the provider server.

Now the only thing missing is a function to check if it is time to refresh the access token.

```
def _send_refresh_request(user_social):
    """
    Private function that refresh an user access token
    """
    strategy = load_strategy()
    try:
        user_social.refresh_token(strategy)
    except HTTPError as exc:
        if exc.response.status_code in (400, 401,):
            raise InvalidCredentialStored(
                message='Received a {} status code from the OAUTH server'.format(
                    exc.response.status_code),
                http_status_code=exc.response.status_code
            )
        raise


def refresh_user_token(user_social):
    """
    Utility function to refresh the access token if is (almost) expired
    Args:
        user_social (UserSocialAuth): a user social auth instance
    """
    try:
        last_update = datetime.fromtimestamp(user_social.extra_data.get('updated_at'))
        expires_in = timedelta(seconds=user_social.extra_data.get('expires_in'))
    except TypeError:
        _send_refresh_request(user_social)
        return
    # small error margin of 5 minutes to be safe
    error_margin = timedelta(minutes=5)
    if datetime.utcnow() - last_update >= expires_in - error_margin:
        _send_refresh_request(user_social)
```

I hope this can be helpful for other people.

Comment: where should i create the function??

Comment: @mohreza which one?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `extra_data` field now has an `auth_time`. You can use this along with `expires` to determine the validity of the `access_token` as such:

```
if (social.extra_data['auth_time'] + social.extra_data['expires'] - 10) <= int(time.time()):
    from social_django.utils import load_strategy
    strategy = load_strategy()
    social.refresh_token(strategy)
```

The extra "10" seconds is in there to prevent a race condition where an `access_token` might expire before further code is executed.

More detail is given in this question: [How can I refresh the token with social-auth-app-django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466731/how-can-i-refresh-the-token-with-social-auth-app-django/42240032?noredirect=1#comment71749013_42240032)