# How can I refresh the token with social-auth-app-django?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I use [Python Social Auth - Django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) to log in my users.

My backend is Microsoft, so I can use [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/) but I don't think that it is relevant.

Python Social Auth deals with authentication but now I want to call the API and for that, I need a valid access token.
Following the [use cases](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#retrieve-google-friends) I can get to this:

```
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='azuread-oauth2')
response = self.get_json('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
                         headers={'Authorization': social.extra_data['token_type'] + ' ' 
                                                   + social.extra_data['access_token']})
```

But the access token is only valid for 3600 seconds and so I need to refresh, I guess I can do it manually but there must be a better solution.
How can I get an access_token refreshed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using `load_strategy()` at `social.apps.django_app.utils`**:

```
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='azuread-oauth2')
strategy = load_strategy()
social.refresh_token(strategy)
```

Now the updated `access_token` can be retrieved from `social.extra_data['access_token']`.

**The best approach is probably to check if it needs to be updated** (customized for AzureAD Oauth2):

```
def get_azuread_oauth2_token(user):
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider='azuread-oauth2')
    if social.extra_data['expires_on'] <= int(time.time()):
        strategy = load_strategy()
        social.refresh_token(strategy)
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

This is based on the method `get_auth_token`from `AzureADOAuth2`. I don't think this method is accessible outside the pipeline, please answer this question if there is any way to do it.

## Updates

### Update 1 - 20/01/2017

Following an [Issue](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/14) to request an extra data parameter with the time of the access token refresh, it is now possible to check if the `access_token` needs to be updated in every backend.

In future versions (>`0.2.1` for the `social-auth-core`) there will be a new field in extra data:

```
'auth_time': int(time.time())
```

And so this works:

```
def get_token(user, provider):
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider=provider)
    if (social.extra_data['auth_time'] + social.extra_data['expires']) <= int(time.time()):
        strategy = load_strategy()
        social.refresh_token(strategy)
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

**Note**: According to [OAuth 2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#appendix-A.14) all responses should (it's a RECOMMENDED param) provide an `expires_in` but for most backends (including the `azuread-oauth2`) this value is being saved as `expires`. Be careful to understand how your backend behaves!
An [Issue](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/40) on this exists and I will be update the answer with the relevant info when it exists.

## Update 2 - 17/02/17

Additionally, there is a method in `UserMixin` called `access_token_expired` ([code](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/9fb7a06a0618aa88d62b980392f77b5a5f91f98f/social_core/storage.py#L94)) that can be used to assert if the token is valid or not (**note**: this method doesn't work for race conditions, as pointed out in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42240032/4470542) by @SCasey).

## Update 3 - 31/05/17

In [Python Social Auth - Core v1.3.0](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/releases/tag/1.3.0) `get_access_token(self, strategy)` was introduced in `storage.py`.

So now:

```
from social_django.utils import load_strategy

social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='azuread-oauth2')
response = self.get_json('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
                     headers={'Authorization': '%s %s' % (social.extra_data['token_type'], 
                                                          social.get_access_token(load_strategy())}
```

Thanks [@damio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075195/damio) for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11):

`.get_access_token(strategy)` refresh the token automatically if it's expired. You can use it like that:

```
from social_django.utils import load_strategy
#...
social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
access_token = social.get_access_token(load_strategy())
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this update. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@NBajanca's update is almost correct for version 1.0.1.

```
extra_data['expires_in']
```

is now

```
extra_data['expires']
```

So the code is:

```
def get_token(user, provider):
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider=provider)
    if (social.extra_data['auth_time'] + social.extra_data['expires']) <= int(time.time()):
        strategy = load_strategy()
        social.refresh_token(strategy)
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

I'd also recommend subtracting an arbitrary amount of time from that calc, so that we don't run into a race situation where we've checked the token 0.01s before expiry and then get an error because we sent the request after expiry. I like to add 10 seconds just to be safe, but it's probably overkill:

```
def get_token(user, provider):
    social = user.social_auth.get(provider=provider)
    if (social.extra_data['auth_time'] + social.extra_data['expires'] - 10) <= int(time.time()):
        strategy = load_strategy()
        social.refresh_token(strategy)
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

**EDIT**
@NBajanca points out that `expires_in` is technically correct per the Oauth2 docs. It seems that for some backends, this may work. The code above using `expires` is what works with `provider="google-oauth2"` as of v1.0.1

Comment: I upvoted for the race condition but you are incorrect about ``expires``. ``expires_in`` is defined in [OAuth 2 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#appendix-A.14) and not in this package.

Comment: PS: I know some backends have this setting "``expires_in`` to ``expires``" but I don't agree. Probably something to be carefull about.

Comment: Ah, the social object above was for provider='google-oauth2' in my case, which has 'expires' rather than 'expires_in' as of v1.0.1. Will make the edit. Also, I opened an issue for this, but it seems 'auth_time' doesn't automatically change when a token is refreshed: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/1089. Would you expect it to?

Comment: The provider is actually ``azuread-oauth2`` but you are correct about ``expires`` in this package. BTW the correct place to create an issue is [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the note on race conditions and ``expires_in``. Being only a Recommended response param, not all providers are required to give it and so the approach will always be by provider.