# How can I return the refresh token using python-social-auth and django-graphql-auth?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

How can I return the refresh token when using social auth? I tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466731/how-can-i-refresh-the-token-with-social-auth-app-django) I don't know how to make this compatible with graphql.

Here is my attempt:

```py
import graphql_social_auth
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token


class SocialAuth(graphql_social_auth.SocialAuthJWT):
    refresh_token = graphene.String()
    token = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, social, **kwargs):
        return cls(
            user=social.user,
            token=get_token(social.user),
            refresh_token=social.extra_data['refresh_token']
        )
```

The user and token fields are alright when I comment out the refresh token. I just don't know where to get the refresh token, it seems to be not in the extra_data.

I am already dealing with this problem for hours and all the search results are no help. Please, any guidance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare the token field again when extending `SocialAuthJWT` because it already has a `token` field from the `JSONWebTokenMixin` mixin unless you need to override it with a different type.

As for the refresh token, you can do something like this to get it:

```
import graphql_social_auth
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import create_refresh_token


class SocialAuth(graphql_social_auth.SocialAuthJWT):
    refresh_token = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, social, **kwargs):
        if social.user.refresh_tokens.count() >= 1:
            refresh_token = social.user.refresh_tokens.last()
        else:
            refresh_token = create_refresh_token(social.user)

        return cls(
            user=social.user,
            token=get_token(social.user),
            refresh_token=refresh_token
        )
```